# Duals of Linear Programs

Tags: linear-programming, game-theory

We are trying to find the dual of the following linear program.

$$ \max_x \ ax_1 \ + x_2 $$

such that:

$$ v_1x_1 - v_2x_2 \geq b_1 \\ v_1x_1 - v_2x_2 \geq b_2 \\
 x_1 \geq 0 \\ x_2 \geq 0$$

How would one do this?

I am not sure but I get the following as the dual :

$$ \min_\gamma \ b_1\gamma_1 + b_2\gamma_2 $$

such that:
$$ v_1\gamma_1 - v_2\gamma_2 \geq a $$

$$ v_1\gamma_1 - v_2\gamma_2 \geq 1 \\ \gamma_1 \geq 0 \\ \gamma_2 \geq 0$$

Is this correct?

What can one say about the primal and dual feasibility and the optimal values of this problem?

Comment: You are missing $V$ in your dual. Also, you need $-b^Tx$ in the dual objective, not $+b^Tx$.

Comment: Thanks. I just edited it. Is that correct now? As for the $ b^Tx  $ I changed it from a maximization to a minimization. So isn't that correct?  I'm also stuck about the primal, dual feasibility and optimal values. Any hints?

Comment: I added an answer and an explanatory perspective below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I employ the method described by Sebastien Lahaie at

http://www.cs.columbia.edu/coms6998-3/lpprimer.pdf

Question: find the dual of the following linear program:

$$ \max_x \ ax_1 \ + x_2 $$

such that:

$$ v_1x_1 - v_2x_2 \geq b_1 \\ v_1x_1 - v_2x_2 \geq b_2 \\
 x_1 \geq 0 \\ x_2 \geq 0$$

Solution:

Steps 1 and 2.

$$ \min_x -ax_1 - x_2$$

such that

$$ v_2x_2 - v_1x_1 +b_1 \le 0 \\ v_2x_2 - v_1x_1 + b_2 \le 0 \\
 x_1 \geq 0 \\ x_2 \geq 0$$

Step 3

$$ \max_ \gamma  \min_x -ax_1 - x_2$$

$$+ \gamma_1(v_2x_2 - v_1x_1 +b_1) \\ + \gamma_2(v_2x_2 - v_1x_1 + b_2)$$

$$x_1 \geq 0 \\ x_2 \geq 0 \\ \gamma_1 \geq 0 \\ \gamma_2 \geq 0$$

Step 4

$$ \max_ \gamma  \min_x \gamma_1 b_1 + \gamma_2 b_2$$

$$ + x_1(-v_1 \gamma_1 -v_1 \gamma_2 -a)$$

$$ + x_2(v_2 \gamma_1 +v_2 \gamma_2 -1)$$

$$x_1 \geq 0 \\ x_2 \geq 0 \\ \gamma_1 \geq 0 \\ \gamma_2 \geq 0$$

Steps 5 and 6

$$ \max_ \gamma  \gamma_1 b_1 + \gamma_2 b_2$$

$$-v_1 \gamma_1 -v_1 \gamma_2 -a \ge 0$$

$$v_2 \gamma_1 +v_2 \gamma_2 -1 \ge 0$$

$$ \gamma_1 \geq 0 \\ \gamma_2 \geq 0$$

Step 7

$$ \min_ \gamma  - \gamma_1 b_1 - \gamma_2 b_2$$

$$-v_1 \gamma_1 -v_1 \gamma_2 \ge a$$

$$v_2 \gamma_1 +v_2 \gamma_2 \ge 1$$

$$ \gamma_1 \geq 0 \\ \gamma_2 \geq 0$$

Comment: Thanks @bluesh34. Can you also comment on the feasibility and optimal solutions?

Comment: Maybe, but I need to check my solution first: think it might be incorrect

Comment: Solution correct now. now i need to consider other questions @Helen

Comment: oops- no spotted another mistake, sorry

Comment: Solution now correct @Helen

Comment: Can you consider the other questions too?

Comment: I am, but I don't know if I'll get those parts

Comment: I get the same result as you now @bluesh34

Comment: You are making some presumptions. If you set $v_1 = -a, v_2 =1, b_1=b_2 = -1$, then the primal is bounded and feasible. I think more delicate reasoning is involved.

Comment: Then I just choose $a = 0$ and make $x_2$ arbitrarily large: the resulting solution is unbounded.

Comment: If you choose $a=0$, then you have the constraint $x_2 \le 1$, which places an upper bound on the primal cost.

Comment: Also, any primal cost at a primal feasible point is a lower bound for the dual, and similarly, any dual cost at a dual feasible point is an upper bound for the primal. This explains why both cannot be unbounded.

Comment: Ok- I see. Thanks for that.

Comment: Answering the last question requires some reasoning about the values of $a,v_i,b_i$. Some requirements are straightforward (for example, feasibility of the dual requires $a \le -1$), others are more tedious.

Comment: Why couldn't you have a feasible dual with a = 5? Also I didn't understand what you said about primal and dual costs even though I gave it +1. I did think the last question would be answered by reasoning about $a$, $v_i$ and $b_i$, but I didn' get to the point where I could see why unbounded primal and dual no simultaneously possible.

Comment: My comment about $a\le -1$ was wrong.

Comment: If a problem is unbounded, it means there are feasible points that have unbounded cost (in the appropriate direction). The primal cost at any feasible primal point is a lower bound for the any feasible dual cost. Hence if the primal has any feasible point, the dual is bounded. The dual cost at any feasible dual point is an upper bound for any primal feasible cost. If the primal is unbounded, then the dual cannot have any feasible points (as these would place a bound on the primal). Similarly for the dual. In particular, they both cannot be unbounded.

Comment: Too much to take in at the moment, but thanks

Comment: @copper.hat thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an informal perspective on the dual that may help with intuition. I use this to quickly derive the transcription when away from my books/notes:

To simplify notation, I am using $\alpha = (a,1)^T$, $V = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & -v_2 \\ v_1 & -v_2 \end{bmatrix}$, $b= (b_1,b_2)^T$.

The primal problem is $\sup_{x \ge 0} \{ \alpha^Tx | V x \ge b \}$.

To incorporate the constraint into the cost, we penalize any violations as follows 
$\sup_{x \ge 0} \inf_{\gamma \ge 0} \alpha^Tx +\gamma^T(Vx-b) $.

Now we magically switch the $\inf$ and $\sup$ (justified by von Neumann minimax, or similar) to get
$\inf_{\gamma \ge 0} \sup_{x \ge 0}  \alpha^Tx +\gamma^T(Vx-b)  = \inf_{\gamma \ge 0} \sup_{x \ge 0}  (\alpha+V^T \gamma)^T x - b^T\gamma$.

If any component of $\alpha+V^T \gamma$ is positve, the cost will be infinite, so we write this as $\inf_{\gamma \ge 0} \{ -b^T \gamma | V^T \gamma \le -\alpha \}$.

So, your problem should be $\min \{ -(b_1 \gamma_1+b_2 \gamma_2) | \gamma_1 \ge 0, \gamma_2 \ge 0, v_1\gamma_1+v_1 \gamma_2 \le -a, -v_2\gamma_1+-v_2 \gamma_2 \le -1 \}$.

To avoid confusion, I would write the primal in a standard form and then just compute the dual in a rote fashion. This avoids many errors.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank-you.

Comment: Can I also get some help on the questions about feasibility and optimal solution?

Comment: I fixed some mistakes; I didn't notice that the $v_2$s has minus signs...